# Sorting a list that have n fixed segments already sorted in ascending order

Tags: algorithm, sorting

The question goes as follows:

> Lists which consist of a small fixed number, n, of segments connected
>   end-to-end, each segment is already in ascending order.

I thought about using mergesort with base case being if equal to n then go back and merge them since we already know that they are sorted, but if I have 3 segments it won't work since I'm dividing by two and you can't divide 3 segments equally into two parts.

The other approach which is similar to merge sort. so I use n stacks for each segment, which we can identify if L[i] > L[i+1] since segments are in ascending order. But I need n comparisons to figure out which element comes first, and I don't know an efficient way of comparing n elements dynamically without using another data structure to compare the elements at the top of the stack.
Also, you are supposed to use the problem feature, segments already ordered, to get better results than conventional algorithms. i.e. complexity less than O(nlogn).

A pseudocode would be nice if you have an idea.

**Edit**:

An example would be [(14,20,22),(7,8,9),(1,2,3)] here we have 3 segments of 3 elements, even though the segments are sorted, the whole list isn't.

p.s. () is there to point out the segments only

Comment: What exactly is the question? What you write does not make sense. Why sort an already sorted list?

Comment: @ichantz added an edit

Comment: so you only need to sort each segment-sublists internally?

Comment: @ichantz indeed, that's our goal

Comment: Run a `for` loop sorting each segment using a `sort()` method. What language are you using? Java has built in sorting methods for collections.

Comment: are the segments guaranteed to be non-overlapping? ie if a segment starts with `a` and ends with `b` does that mean that no other segment will have a number `x` such that `a<x<b`?

Comment: I guess this is what you want
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22055495/algorithm-to-merge-multiple-sorted-sequences-into-one-sorted-sequence-in-c

Comment: Look for **natural** merge sort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think maybe you've misunderstood mergesort.  While usually you would split in half and sort each half before merging, it's really the merging part which makes the algorithm.  You just need to merge on runs instead.

With your example of `[(14,20,22),(7,8,9),(1,2,3)]`

After first merge you have `[(7, 8, 9, 14, 20, 22),(1, 2, 3)]`

After second merge you have `[(1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 14, 20, 22)]`

```
l = [14, 20, 22, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3]

rl = [] # run list
sl = [l[0]] # temporary sublist

#split list into list of sorted sublists
for item in l[1:]:
    if item > sl[-1]:
        sl.append(item)
    else:
        rl.append(sl)
        sl = [item]
rl.append(sl)
print(rl)

#function for merging two sorted lists
def merge(l1, l2):
    l = [] #list we add into
    while True:
        if not l1:
            # first list is empty, add second list onto new list
            return l + l2
        if not l2:
            # second list is empty, add first list onto new list 
            return l + l1
        if l1[0] < l2[0]:
            # rather than deleting, you could increment an index
            # which is likely to be faster, or reverse the list
            # and pop off the end, or use a data structure which
            # allows you to pop off the front
            l.append(l1[0])
            del l1[0]
        else:
            l.append(l2[0])
            del l2[0]

# keep mergins sublists until only one remains
while len(rl) > 1:
    rl.append(merge(rl.pop(), rl.pop()))

print(rl)
```

It's worth noting that unless this is simply an excercise, you are probably better off using whatever inbuilt sorting function your language of choice uses.